# Generating a barrel when calling ng g component <myName>

Tags: angular-cli

Currently if I call `ng g component user` angular-cli generates 
user.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts files inside teh `app/user` directory as one would expect.

However it doesn't generate a barrel - eg a file called `index.ts` that contains:

```
export * from "./user.component"
```

is there any way I can configure cli to generate barrel files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not available in the angular-cli. The idea of barrels is still present, but less prominent with the introductions of `NgModule` for code organization.

In the future the CLI will allow for custom blueprints/generation templates which you will able to tweak to your needs.